# jqueryui Add sortable component dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi i'm having a problem creating a dynamically sortable list, the idea is have a button to create a list, the list has some option like add new item to itself or drag them between lists, i have a main list like that:

**TL;DR:**
Create and initialize a new sortable list from a ul just insertered in the DOM

```
<ul class="list-1">
 <li id="dynamic-id" class="first-level-items">
    - Some content -
 </li>
<ul>
```

Everything works fine there, there is an action to add more ".first-level-item" and works fine, but inside those elements is and action to create  another another list and inside the list other list items, so the structure should be something like:

```
<ul class="list-1">
 <li id="dynamic-id" class="first-level-items">
    <ul class="dynamic-list" id="dynamic-list-id">
       <li class="dynamic-generate-li">
          - content -
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
<ul>
```

My constructor functions:

```
createNewCategoryRow: function(parent,obj){
        var controller =this;
        var insertAfter = $('[data-parent-ul="'+parent+'"]');
        var element = "<li data-id='"+obj.uniqueId+"' id='"+obj.uniqueId+"' ><div class='row sub-title-inner' data-obj='"+obj.uniqueId+"'>" +
                          "<div class='cell cell-2 row-title '>"+
                            "<span class='span-title'><i> "+obj.value+" </i></span>"+
                          "</div>"+
                        "</div>";

            element +=  "<ul class='sort sort-"+obj.uniqueId+"' data-parent='"+obj.uniqueId+"'></ul>"+                      
                        "<div class='row bold title-total-child-inner'>"+
                          "<div class='cell cell-2 '>"+
                            "<span class='span-title'><strong> "+ obj.total.value+" </strong></span>"+
                          "</div>";

        for(var i = 0; i < obj.total.amounts.length; i++){
            element += "<div class='cell overflow-cell' id='"+ obj.total.amounts[i].uniqueId +"'>"+ obj.total.amounts[i].value  +"</div>";
        }                
            element += "</div></li>";

        insertAfter.append( element);
        insertAfter.sortable('refresh')

        //Here Everything works as expected


        //Here nope 
        //Initialize the new generate ul container Not working :(
        $('.sort-'+obj.uniqueId).sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            cancel: ".cancel-sort",
            axis: 'y',          

            update: function(e, ui) {
                $("ul.sort li").find('div.row').removeClass("gray");
                $('.sort-'+obj.uniqueId+" li:even").find('div.row').addClass("gray");
            },
            stop: function(e, ui) {
                var cctManager = Client.CCTManager.create();
                var idArr =  $.map($(this).children('li'), function(el) {
                                return el.id ;
                            })

                var me = ui.item.data('id'); 

                var position = idArr.indexOf(me);

                cctManager.dragCriteriaGroup(_workpage, me, position, function(newWorkpage){
                    controller.set('saved_workpage',newWorkpage);                   
                })


            }
        }).disableSelection();
    }
```

//create the item lists for the new list container (ul)

```
createNewCriteriaRow:function(id,obj){

        var insertAfter = $('[data-parent="'+id+'"]');
        var element = "<li  data-obj='"+obj.uniqueId+"' id='"+obj.uniqueId+"'>"+
                          "<div class='row'>"+
                            "<div class='cell cell-2 row-title'>"+
                              "<span class='span-title'>"+obj.value+"</span>"+
                            "</div>";

        for(var i = 0; i < obj.amounts.length; i++){
            element += "<div class='cell overflow-cell' data-obj='"+ obj.amounts[i].uniqueId +"'>"+ obj.amounts[i].value  +"</div>";
        }                           

        element += "</div></li>"

        insertAfter.append(element);
        //Until here everything works as expected

        //Here i'm trying to refresh the last created item and add some style to the childs, it add the childs but not refresh the sortable           
        console.log(id)
        $('.sort-'+id + 'location').find('div.row').removeClass("gray");
        $('.sort-'+id + 'li:even').find('div.row').addClass("gray");
        $('.sort-'+id).sortable( "refresh" );

    }
```

Both elements works on click.

Thanks

Comment: It could be usefull if you added more code into a jsfiddle (or jsbin, or even a snippet here in SO) with the basic structure you already have, with the buttons and everything. Or at least a link to your working site.

Comment: ok, this is a example http://jsbin.com/jafucixerubi/1/edit is not the real code because it is doit with emberjs and handlebars and are like 3000 lines between files. but that is the idea, it helps?

Comment: I was thinking more of a strip-it-down-to-the-basics stuff. Besides, you have quite a lot of syntax errors. Please review your code, and mark with css backgrounds the lists you're trying to create. Also, I still don't see the buttons to add the new list.